# how can i package spring boot project ,then i can use it in jni program written by c?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-native-interface

i create a simple spring boot project like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args )
{
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
    app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);
    System.out.println("serv main");
}
```

package it

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>com.gutongfei.lab.Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

last i use it in jni :

```
JNIEnv *env;
JavaVMInitArgs vmArgs;
JavaVMOption options[3];

vmArgs.version             = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
vmArgs.ignoreUnrecognized  = JNI_TRUE;
vmArgs.nOptions            = 0;

char classpath[1024]    = "-Djava.class.path=fishnet.jar";//build by maven

options[0].optionString = strcat(classpath, classPath);
vmArgs.nOptions++;

options[1].optionString = "abort";
options[1].extraInfo    = (void *)&myAbortHook;
vmArgs.nOptions++;
options[2].optionString = "exit";
options[2].extraInfo    = (void *)&myExitHook;
vmArgs.nOptions++;

vmArgs.options          = options;
jint res    = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&sJvm, (void **)&env, &vmArgs);
jclass argClass  = (*env)->FindClass(env, "FishnetArg");
jmethodID   cid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, argClass,"<init>", "()V");
(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, entreeClass, inputMid,argObj);
...
```

but,it fails with error:
Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.gutongfei.lab.Main]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories.

my question is how should i build the spring boot project ,then i can use it in jni program?

Comment: Using spring-boot-starter-parent  plugin in pom.xml will work fine and will find the correct main class automatically

Comment: i need use spring boot framework in jni 。